# Vue 2: Can't Get Past "Cannot Read Property"

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I just upgraded my app to Vue 2 and I can’t seem to get past this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at
>   VueComponent.showChoices (eval at  (app.js:310),
>   :33:32)”

. I thought I was protecting from that with a conditional but this error has plagued me now for 3 hours. Here’s showChoices:

```
showChoices() {
    if(this.filtered) {
        if (this.search.length > 2 && this.filtered.length > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are testing `filtered` and trying to access length of `search`. So `search` must be null.

Comment: search is declared locally in data as search: null. Is that not how to do it?

Comment: So you experiemce an error that tells you you have a null object, you know you have a null object, and post a question why you have an error about accessing the prop of a null object? I don't follow what the actual problem is sorry.

Comment: I wasn't considering search as a potential problem because I had declared it locally to the component -- just a blind spot on my part. I am now using search: '' to declare it so it isn't null and still doing the checks. Sometimes after hours of focusing on a problem, you just need fresh eyes. As SOON as you mentioned search, the problem was solved. THANKS for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `null` value doesn't have a `length` property.
As you commented `this.search` is null. Didn't you mean to do this?:

```
showChoices() {
  if (this.search && this.filtered) {
    if (this.search.length > 2 && this.filtered.length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: ...or simply initialize `search` as an empty array instead of `null`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add null checks as well, like following:

```
showChoices() {
    if (this.search && this.search.length > 2 && this.filtered && this.filtered.length > 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```